# How to get the first character of each word in "HTML" Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to extract the initials of "User 10" as U1 in HTM. I am able to extract the first and the last as U0, but I want **U1.**
This is how I am getting U0:

```
 <div class="initials">
       {{ chat.name | slice:0:1 }}
       {{ chat.name.slice(-1) }}
 </div>
```

I need to do this in my .html file, cannot do it .js/ts.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `split` to split the string into words, then take the first character of each word.

Comment: What template system is this? This isn't an HTML question.

Comment: I'm using javascript into an HTML file

Comment: @this.jind no you aren't. You're using some sort of template language. Angular perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of word, but this one is reasonable.

```js
[...string.matchAll(/\b\w/g)].join('')
```

That is, find every word character (`\w`) that immediately follows a word boundary (`\b`), put them in an array, then join them together.

You should be able to use this expression directly, or implement it as a pipe.

```js
function initials(string) {
  return [...string.matchAll(/\b\w/g)].join('')
}

console.log(initials("User 10"))
console.log(initials("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
console.log(initials("Twenty-one. N_x, 4.2"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Making the function worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.split(' ').map((w) => w[0]).join("")
```

This solution does not handle punctuation, but you can add a filter later

Comment: `trim`ming the string value and then `split`ting it at each whitespace(sequence) with a regex like `/\s+/` is even more generic / failsafe.